# Schema in MongoDb

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, nosql

I am using SQL server 2008, and I have created one Database called `DemoDb` as you can see in below image. I am migrating this existing database to **MongoDb** now. **But** I am not aware about `Schemas` in mongodb. In below image in **red square** you can see the `schemas` like admin, login, User etc.

**My Question** is how I can migrate or **create** this kind of schema in mongodb. ?

can you please suggest me or help me.

Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated ...

Thanks
[image]

Comment: This is a resource that I've found helpful for relating relational database design to MongoDB: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/mapping-relational-databases-and-sql-to-mongodb--net-35650

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/) at least?

There is a chapter [`SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) which have a useful information for you.

> **SQL Terms/Concepts** - **MongoDB Terms/Concepts**
>
> table - collection
>
> row - document or BSON document
>
> column - field
>
> table joins - $lookup, embedded documents
>
> ...

There is no other way as you must familiarize yourself with MongoDB basics at least.

P.S. [MongoDB University](https://university.mongodb.com/) have a free courses.